# Resource name for getIdentifier()

Tags: android, resources, identifier

Where can I find names for resources to use in `getIndetifier()` like in the example below?

```
Int resId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
```

Comment: Why do you need those? Maybe there's a simpler way to implement your desired functionality.

Comment: @npace I want to change color of Positive and Negative buttons in DialogPreference

Comment: Then you will want `@+id/button1` , `@+id/button2` , `@+id/button3` (see my answer)

Comment: @Blundell Have just found it by myself, but thank you.

Comment: @Blundell by the way, is there any other approach to implement the color change?

Comment: create a custom dialog I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alertTitle` is here

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog_holo.xml#L51

From what I know there is not one single document that will list you them all. You will have to be more specific about what area you want to look in then browse the Android source code.

- https://github.com/android
- https://android.googlesource.com/
- http://androidxref.com/
- http://blog.blundell-apps.com/add-source-code-links-to-android-apis/